# How to Use Case with AND in SQL in subquery

Tags: sql

Like - AND `CASE WHEN $P{MasteParam}='SERVICE' then SERVICE=V.SERVICE end`

Actually, I need to compare 2 columns SERVICE=V.SERVICE in a case in the subquery –

This is not working for me.

Please help?

Comment: please provide the full context, from your question nothing makes clear

Comment: It's generally much better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is implement simple conditioning in your WHERE clause, you can either write it this way (without `CASE`):

```
(...)
AND (($P{MasteParam} = 'SERVICE' AND SERVICE=V.SERVICE)
     OR $P{MasteParam} != 'SERVICE')
```

or this way (with `CASE`):

```
(...)
AND V.SERVICE = CASE 
                  WHEN $P{MasteParam} = 'SERVICE'
                  THEN SERVICE
                  ELSE V.SERVICE
                END
```

Comparing `SERVICE=V.SERVICE`*inside* the `CASE` is not possible, by design and syntax, but using `CASE` as in my second suggestion makes the same thing and allows you to use `ELSE` expression to define what you want to do when `$P{MasteParam} = 'SERVICE'` condition is not met.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. Actually, I need to compare column SERVICE=V.SERVICE in case in subquery

Comment: @GimmyDagar Comparing SERVICE=V.SERVICEinside the CASE is not possible, by design and syntax, but using CASE as in my second suggestion makes the same thing and allows you to use ELSE expression to define what you want to do when $P{MasteParam} = 'SERVICE' condition is not met. I added that explanation to my answer also.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
SELECT 
  ....
  CASE WHEN Country = 'Germany' AND ContactName LIKE 'M%'
    THEN 'Match'
    ELSE 'No match'
  END 
  AS [doing some matching]
  ...
FROM ... ...
```

What I notice in your code is that you have something like '*then SERVICE=V.SERVICE*', this looks like an update statement in the select-clause.

And I have to admit I do not recognize the *$P{MasteParam}='SERVICE'* syntax. Which database server do you use (as there are some differences between SQL-server, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc)?